# AHK Send Key Random Number of Times

Tags: autohotkey

I want to replace the letter `q` with a random number of 5-10 `q`s while typing.

Here is the code I'm trying. Any suggestions?

```
Random, rand, 5, 10
send {z %rand%}
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requires the keyboard hook to be used by adding

```
#UseHook
```

in the auto-execute-section

or
using the $-prefix:

```
$q::
    Random, rand, 5, 10
    send {q %rand%}
return
```